# Firebase & Push Notifications / Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not able to get a single push notification sent to my device I've set up a demo app with their demo app-delegate, did sign it with a provisioning profile, with an push-notification enabled app and uploaded my .p12 to the firebase admin panel, but no matter what I try (resigning everything,.. and so on) I'm not able to send a push message through the firebase console.
What am I missing here?

Edit: I did try to send to the whole segment and also to a single device (with the id, given in the console)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Register for remote notifications
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            // [START register_for_notifications]
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            // [END register_for_notifications]
        } else {
            // Fallback
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }

        FIRApp.configure()

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you are deploying this code to a device, or using the simulator? Also, posting the logs helps. I have an app with working APN through Firebase. Just as a quick test, can you subscribe to any topic after connecting to `FIRMessaging`? For example: `FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribeToTopic("/topics/issues")`

Comment: Thank's for your comment, but I really forgot the didRegisterRemoteNotification. Oh I'm so blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that you are calling `setAPNSToken`, perhaps that's what you are missing?

```
// AppDelegate.m
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [firebaseManager didRegisterRemoteNotifications:deviceToken];
}

// FirebaseManager.swift
func didRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken: NSData) {

    let type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType
    #if DEBUG
        type = .Sandbox
    #else
        type = .Prod
    #endif

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: type)
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! I could swear I had it in, but it was missing. Kind of annoying as I did follow the docs @ firebase.google.com, but they suck anyway. I preferred the old non google-style docs of firebase < 3.0 more :)

Comment: @LucèBrùlè yeah, for real.. Firebase legacy docs were a masterpiece. Also, I've answered a lot of trivial questions about firebase here on SO recently due to their poor new documentation.